# Is it wrong to say "Tu vas te perdre encore" ?

Tags: sens, adverbes

The intended meaning is *You are going to get lost again.* The actual translation is *Tu vas encore te perdre*. But is it completely wrong to say *Tu vas te perdre encore*? If it is not totally wrong grammatically, does it carry a different meaning? Can it be used that way to change the stress in the sentence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Tu vas encore te perdre* is the normal unstressed way to say it. But you are right *encore* could be placed after the verb to create an effect.

When writing I would introduce a coma before *encore*.

- *Tu vas te perdre, encore*.
  and when speaking make a pause before *encore.*

Having *encore* after the verb shows insistence or exasperation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It was marked wrong in the French learning website. Do you think *Tu vas te perdre encore* is an impossible translation for *You are going to get lost again* ?

Comment: @Xfce4  To my mind **as long as there is a comma** it is a possible translation, so it depends on what is intended. It is always difficult to isolate sentences from their context. If the *French learning website* you mention is Duolingo, it's one of their flaws, and some of the explanations given are often surprising - to say the least.